# Are OCMock and Nocilla incompatible?

Tags: objective-c, ocmock, nocilla

I am trying to use both OCMock and Nocilla in the same set of unit tests.  I used CocoaPods to install them both, and reference them using

```
#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>
#import <Nocilla/Nocilla.h>
```

But when I try to use Nocilla's .andReturn in the following way (where subscriptionData is an NSData *):

```
stubRequest(@"GET", @"https://api.test.com/api/beaconinbox/subscriptions/list").andReturn(200).withBody(subscriptionData);
```

I get a compiler error that looks like this:

> /Users/ravi/GitHub/Mobile/ClinicalInbox/ClinicalInboxTests/ClinicalInboxTests.m:63:93: Property '_andReturn' not found on object of type 'LSStubRequestDSL *'

Which persists until I remove the `#import "<OCMock/OCMock.h>"` from my code.  Then all my tests run perfectly.

Is there a known incompatibility with OCMock and Nocilla?  I couldn't seem to find one anywhere - in fact I've seen just the opposite - many examples of people using both in the same test framework all the time.  So I must assume I'm doing something wrong, can anyone tell me what?

Comment: It is also possible to "fix" the error by placing a `#undef andReturn` in-between importing OCMock and Nocilla.  Which would indicate a possible incompatibility in the two libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OCMock does define a macro named `andReturn`, which has one argument. If Nocilla also uses something called `andReturn` that has a single argument then that's an incompatibility. As mentioned above, it can be avoided by undefining the `andReturn` macro from OCMock. This obviously means that it's not possible to use that part of OCMock's syntax afterwards.

Comment: I agree.  I was just surprised by the incompatibility since I saw so many examples of people using the libraries at the same time.  It's an unfortunate side effect of using macros to implement your behavior I guess, but I understand why both libraries did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both by using standard square bracket notation, e.g.:

```
[stubRequest(@"GET", myURL) andReturn](200).withBody(body);
```

Ugly, but it works.